# Finding the PDF of Y

Tags: calculus, statistics, derivatives, poisson-distribution

I have this equation [image] and from this I need to obtain the PDF of Y.

I have the solution but the steps aren't clear.

The answer I have is [image]

But I have been given no steps - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check your first equation? I think it has typos. In particular, I think you mean $F_Y(t)$, not $Fy(t)$, and I think you may mean $(\lambda t)^u$ and not $\lambda\cdot t^u$.

Comment: Basically, to get the answer, just differentiate both sides with respect to $t$ (remember, $PDF = CDF')$; note the minus sign will be present on the left side, and you will need to use the product rule on the right side. You may find it helpful to just write out the terms of the series explicitly (there are only three terms) and forget the summation notation. Note that the term for $u=0$ doesn't really look like the other terms, so it will behave differently when you take the derivative.

Comment: Sorry I've just adjusted it now.

Comment: It is hard to identify where the mistake(s) is(are). For instance here $\sum\limits_{u=0}^2 e^t \frac{\lambda (\lambda t)^u}{u-1}$. For $u=1$ the fraction is not defined. Ask the lecturer to explain the exercise and the solution. Maybe you give him some formatting tips.

Comment: Yes these are solutions provided by a lecturer - I am just as baffled by the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many typographical errors in the provided solution, and now you still have to evaluate *two* summations in the solution. Less painful would be to write out the summations from the get-go:
$$
1- F(t) = \sum_{u=0}^2 e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^u}{u!}=e^{-\lambda t}\left(1 + \lambda t +\frac{(\lambda t)^2}{2!}\right)\tag1
$$
Having cleared out the summation notation, now differentiate both sides of (1). Use the product rule on the RHS of (1) to obtain
$$
-f(t)=-\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\left(1 + \lambda t +\frac{(\lambda t)^2}{2!}\right)+e^{-\lambda t}\Big(0 + \lambda  +\lambda(\lambda t)\Big).\tag2
$$
Multiply (2) through by $-1$, and simplify:
$$
f(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\left(1 +\lambda t+ \frac{(\lambda t)^2}{2!}-1 -\lambda t\right)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^2}{2!}.
$$